# WPF System.InvalidCastException in scrollbar template

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to make a style for a horizontal/vertical scrollbar. I'm getting the following error when I attempt to run the program:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'MS.Internal.NamedObject' to type 'System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate'.

Visual studio just gives me a generic error popup and intelisense doesn't show any errors. I have no details to go on so I have no idea what the problem could be. I've compared my code with an existing style I have for a vertical scrollbar but nothing stands out.

Here's my app.xaml:

```
 <Application x:Class="Animated_Icon_Maker.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Animated_Icon_Maker"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:Animated_Icon_Maker.ViewModels"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:IAnimated_Icon_Maker.Views">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="{x:Type ScrollBar}"  TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
                <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <!--<Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="18" />
                        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource HorizontalScrollBar}" />
                    </Trigger>-->
                    <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical">
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="18" />
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto" />
                        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource VerticalScrollBar}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>

            <ControlTemplate x:Key="HorizontalScrollBar" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">

            </ControlTemplate>

            <ControlTemplate x:Key="VerticalScrollBar" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                <Grid Background="{x:Null}" Width="10">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="0.00001*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Track x:Name="PART_Track" Grid.Row="0" IsDirectionReversed="true" Focusable="false">
                        <Track.Thumb>
                            <Thumb x:Name="Thumb" Background="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Style="{DynamicResource ScrollThumbs}" />
                        </Track.Thumb>
                        <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                            <RepeatButton x:Name="PageUp" Command="ScrollBar.PageDownCommand" Opacity="0" Focusable="false" />
                        </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                        <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                            <RepeatButton x:Name="PageDown" Command="ScrollBar.PageUpCommand" Opacity="0" Focusable="false" />
                        </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                    </Track>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>


        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

The style is straight from the Microsoft docs here:
[learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/scrollbar-styles-and-templates) and the ControlTemplate is from my working vertical scrollbar style.

Any ideas what's wrong?

**EDIT**

If I comment out

```
<Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource VerticalScrollBar}" />
```

the exception goes away so I've at least narrowed it down to my vertical scrollbar ControlTemplate.

Comment: Without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, not possible to say for sure what the issue is. However, that exception typically happens when you've put a special value like `Binding.DoNothing` or `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` someplace it doesn't belong.

Comment: My code is the complete style so far, you just have to copy/paste it into your app.xaml file, that alone should cause the app to crash.

Comment: I've included my full app.xaml. Don't know what else I could do.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research on the difference between `DynamicResources` and `StaticResources`, I discovered that you must define the xaml your `StaticResources` point to before attempting to use them.

So, since I was setting the template values to `StaticResources` in the triggers, I had to define the `ControlTemplates` in the xaml before the Style that was was using them.

Alternatively I could have switched to `DynamicResources` instead and the xaml order wouldn't have mattered.